# show an error when values within range are inserted into sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am making a database which stores my latitude and longitude in sqlite. I want to make sure that if the co-ordinates generated are within range of 0.500 of previously inserted co-ordinates , my system will show me a toast saying pre-reported.
I did try it using insertWithOnConflict but its not working can please someone help and i appreciate your suggesions thank you :)

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    Button btnAddData;
    Button btnviewAll;
    Button getLocationBtn;
    TextView locationText;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        getLocationBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getLocationBtn);
        locationText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locationText);

        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);
        btnviewAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);

        AddData();

        viewAll();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 101);

        }


        getLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getLocation();
            }
        });
    }

    public  void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(locationText.getText().toString() );
                        if(isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"already reported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void viewAll() {
        btnviewAll.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
                        if(res.getCount() == 0) {
                            // show message
                            showMessage("Error","Nothing found");
                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Name :"+ res.getString(0)+"\n");
                        }

                        // Show all data
                        showMessage("Data",buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(Message);
        builder.show();
    }


    void getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 5, this);
        }
        catch(SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locationText.setText("Latitude " + location.getLatitude() + "\n Longitude " + location.getLongitude());



    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

**DatabasehELPER.JAVA**

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Student.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student_table";
    public static final String COL_2 = "name";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( name FLOAT UNIQUE)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);

        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }






    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: any exception ??

Comment: not it did not give me an error or exception when i tried with insertWithOnConflict but it when i tried inserting co-ordinates of same location, it allowed that

Comment: I only saw Data Inserted, no  pre-reported

Comment: hmm... that is whats been happening in my device..... since i reported at the  same location it should have said pre reported since it was already present in database but instead it added that to database again. its been bothering me from last few days

Comment: your code only have `Data Inserted` and `already reported`. Where did `pre-reported` come from ?

Comment: already reported and pre reported are the same things... i meant the same .... sorry if i was not clear enough in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this. If data already exists, it will display 
"Data Inserted", otherwise it will display "already reported" and then add data

```
     boolean check;

       btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                check =  myDb.checkDuplicate(locationText.getText().toString());
                if(check == true)
                {
                   myDb.insertData(locationText.getText().toString());
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"already reported",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else{
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }                
       });
```

**checkDuplicate and insertData function**

```
   public  boolean checkDuplicate(String name) {
  String Query = ""; // your query
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
      if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
      cursor.close();
      return false;
     }
      cursor.close();
      return true;
  }

 public void insertData(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    }
```

Comment: thank you it works. but i wanted exactly opposite of this. ie. if data already exists in the database it should say "already reported" and that data must not enter the database, and if new data is inserted it should say "data inserted " and then add that data to database

Comment: also i added checkduplicate in my databasehelper.java but when i called it in mainactivity.java it shows cannot resolve method "checkduplicate"

Comment: @PrajwalIngale needs to be in quotes i.e. `SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE name = 'Latitude 19.2214163 Longitude 73.0813848'`

Comment: thanks guys it worked... if you ever visit india do come to my home... i believe you know the adress ;)